# How to know only new values comparing two arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have two arrays (Java):

```
  ArrayList<String> arrA = new ArrayList<String>();
  arrA.addAll(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"0", "1", "2", "3", "4"}));

  ArrayList<String> arrB = new ArrayList<String>();
  arrB.addAll(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "X", "6", "7"}));
```

And I need to know how fills a third array only the new values found in the second array. I try to do loops but it didn't work well.

Any idea?

Comment: Please add you not working code and debug information.

Comment: Can you show us what you did and describe what exactly is not working well?

Comment: `ArrayList<String> arrC = new ArrayList<>(arrB); arrC.removeAll(arrA);`.

Comment: If you want to know all elements of `arrB` that are not in `arrA` you just need to **remove all** elements in `arrA` from `arrB`.

Comment: Arrays and instances of the `ArrayList` class are not the same thing.

Comment: One minute please, I added if statement inside the loops, but the results are wrong.

I found a solution with String arrays, but I'm trying with ArrayLists.

Comment: "One minute please, I added if statement inside the loops, but the results are wrong" please show your code. We can't say what's wrong with it without seeing it.

Comment: @AndyTurner I tested your code and it's a practical solution to the problem at hand, thanks. If you want, you can post it as an answer to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the differences of two ArrayLists with the following code:

```
ArrayList<String> differences = new ArrayList<>(arrB);
differences.removeAll(arrA);
```

Then you will have a new `ArrayList<String> differences`, that contains all the strings your first ArrayList doesn't have.

If you want to do this multiple times you simply have to update your lists:

```
arrA = new ArrayList<>(arrB);
arrB.add("f");
arrB.add("e");
```

And then you can simply rerun the first code segment.